# How can i change Kendo UI for angular default styles

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I want to change the styles from the default datepicker to something like the second image. Is there a way to acomplish that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can biuld your own theme and check out what telerik already done at [kendo-ui theme builder](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/themebuilder/)